# Time-independent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

For the Time-independent perturbation theory in quantum mechanics in my textbook the eigenenergies $E_n$ and the mixing coefficents $c_{nm}$ are given as

> [image: Blockquote]

I do not know where they go this form, the only note that they say is:

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: They did not get them from anywhere. They are the *definitions* of the  quantities $E_n^{(1)}$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a derived quantity. This is a *definition*. You are probably familiar with the usual form of a Taylor expansion. Let's say we want to expand $f(\lambda)$ around $\lambda=0$.
$$f(\lambda)=f(0)+\lambda f'(0)+\lambda^2 f''(0)+\dots$$
You can also define this as
$$f=f^{(0)}+\lambda f^{(1)}+\lambda^2f^{(2)}+\dots$$
Here the superscript $(n)$ doesn't mean anything$^\dagger$, it's just a label to indicate it is the $n$-th term in the series expansion. Note that we don't use the fact that $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$. The series expansion is just a nice bookkeeping tool and ensures that the approximate solution gets better if you take higher orders. What you are basically doing is solving
$$(H_0+\lambda H')|\psi_n(\lambda)\rangle=E_n(\lambda)|\psi_n(\lambda)\rangle$$
up to some order in $\lambda$. Here $H_0$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian, $H'$ is the perturbation and $H=H_0+H'$ is the perturbed Hamiltonian. For $\lambda=1$ we get the exact perturbed Schrödinger equation
$$(H_0+ H')|\psi_n\rangle=E_n|\psi_n\rangle$$
so if we just plug in $\lambda=1$ in our approximate solution we solve the perturbed Schrödinger equation up to some order.

The mixing coefficients are a complicated but convenient way to solve for $\psi(\lambda)$. In Griffith's they use $\psi=\psi^{(0)}+\lambda \psi^{(1)}+\lambda^2 \psi^{(2)}$ instead of the mixing coefficients but these are equivalent approaches.

$\dagger$ Actually now that I think of it you can interpret it as being a derivative without a problem. Pick whichever definition that you like most.

Answer (score 0):

You are aiming to solve the differential equation:

$$ \tag{1}
    H \Psi_n = (H_o + H_1) \Psi_n = E_n \Psi_n
$$

Where $H_1$ is the perturbed Hamiltonian $H_1 = \lambda V$, and $H_0$ is the unperturbed Hamiltonian. The eigen functions $\phi_n$ of $H_0$ are known:

$$ \tag{2}
    H_0 \phi_n = \epsilon_n^0 \phi_n
$$

Trying to solve Eq.(1), we expand $\Psi$ in terms of $\phi$:

$$ \tag{3}
  \Psi_n = \sum_m c_{nm} \phi_m
$$

Then you substitute Eq.(3) into Eq.(1), try to find the expansion coefficients $c_{nm}$ and the eigen energy $E_n$.

The pertubation method is to define $E_n$ and $c_{nm}$ in sequential order of $\lambda$, the perturbed strength  $H_1 = \lambda V$. Of course, the zeroth order will be Eq.(2):

$$
   E_n^{(0)} = \epsilon_n; \\
   c_{nm}^{(0)} = \delta_{nm}.
$$

To the next order of $\lambda$, we introduce two new parmeters $E_n^{(1)}$ and $c_{nm}^{(1)}$:

$$ \tag{4}
   E_n \approx \epsilon_n + \lambda E_n^{(1)}; \\
   c_{nm} \approx \delta_{nm} + \lambda c_{nm}^{(1)}.
$$

Then you substitute Eq.(4) into Eq(1). Solve Eq. (1) by equating each same order of $\lambda$. You will be able to solve two new parameters: $E_n^{(1)}$ and $c_{nm}^{(1)}$.

The above equations you post are the forms for $E_n$ and $c_{nm}$ with all different order put together. You substitute them into Eq.(1), separate equation for each order of $\lambda$ and solve the new parameters of each order, iteratively.